# Проблемы tinyMCE при загрузке файла в Laravel 6

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, tinymce

Пытаюсь настроить загрузку файлов в tinyMCE, но что то совсем плохо. При загрузке изображения очень сильное ощущение, что post летит куда угодно, кроме нужного роута. Как результат **в xhr.responseText попадает текущая страница** и, соответсвенно, происходит ошибка: *SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data* (ясно почему - там идет html разметка страницы).

Подключение скриптов и пропись роута к обработчику картинок

```
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const config = {
            image_path : "{{route('admin.image_json')}}"
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/MyAddScripts.js') }}" defer></script>
@endsection
```

инициализация tinymce - файл js/MyAddScripts.js

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tinyM',
    plugins: 'image paste',
    paste_data_images: true,
    file_picker_types: 'file image media',
    toolbar: 'image',
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', config.image_path);
        var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", csrf);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                console.log('Eep - it ', xhr.status);
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }
            console.log(xhr.response);
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                console.log('Here');
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }
            success(json.location);
        };
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
        xhr.send(formData);
    },
    });
```

роуты прописаны
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам метод, отвечающий за возврат json response

```
public function mceditUploadImage(ImageRequest $request)
{
    $image = $this->saveImage($request, new Image());
    return response()->json(['location' => $image->name ]);
}
```

место, где происходит ошибка

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    ...
    json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: Так вы посмотрите, на какой роут фактически отправляется через devTools браузера.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko , смотрел и он был правильным ) Собственно проблема решена и была в обычной челевеческой усталости и, как следствие, невинмательности. Вечером нужно будет ответ оформить) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На свежую голову стало очевидно, что **" в xhr.responseText попадает текущая страница  "** - это результат работы валидации request-a в методе

```
public function mceditUploadImage(ImageRequest $request)
```

по причине не совпадения названия поля: "image" в валидации и "file" ajax запросе

```
formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
```